# why is this code not compiling with javac but has no errors in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, javac

the following code:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Constraint(validatedBy = {
        MinTimeIntCoConstraintValidator.class, 
        MinTimeIntCoListConstraintValidator.class,
        MinTimeDoubleCoConstraintValidator.class, 
        MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class,
        })
@Documented
public @interface MinTimeValueCo
{
    int value();
    String message() default "value does not match minimum requirements";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

compiled in eclipse but fails to compile in sun/oracle compiler:

```
> MinTimeValueCo.java:19: illegal start of expression
>     [javac]       })
>     [javac]       ^
>     [javac] 1 error
```

This happened because of the comma after `MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class,`.

when I removed the comma it works fine:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {
        MinTimeIntCoConstraintValidator.class, 
        MinTimeIntCoListConstraintValidator.class,
        MinTimeDoubleCoConstraintValidator.class, 
        MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class
        })
```

I am using jdk 1.6.0.10.
Do you know why this is illegal and compiling in eclipse?

Comment: Most interesting stuff. On an unrelated note, I have always thought that Eclipse uses javac, too. Thanks for the enlightenment :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug in Java 6's `javac`. [The JLS allows trailing commas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) in some places and the Eclipse compiler follows the standard here while Java 6 never allows trailing commas anywhere.

You can try to compile your code with `javac` from Java 7 with the options `-source 6 -target 6` (to get Java 6 compatible byte code). If the bug is still there, [file it](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/web/bugzilla.html). It might get fixed.

Comment: Apperantly this is fixed in java 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `,` at the end of `MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class,` it is looking for another expression in the list.

Comment: A trailing comma is allowed according to the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7

Comment: this means that javac does not follow the JLS?

Comment: This does look like a `javac` bug, which version are you using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are quite correct, perhaps it is something to do with javac itself?

Comment: 1.6.0.10 is really old, try updating to a newer version like 1.6.0.32 and see if it still happens

Comment: It's a but in `javac`; the JLS allows some trailing commas and the Eclipse compiler follows the standard here while `javac` never allows trailing commas anywhere (at least in Java 6). You may try Java 7 to compile the code with `-target 6`.

Answer (score 0):

By having a comma after `MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class`, the java compiler thinks there should be another value. Eclipse accepts the trailing comma, but javac does not.

Comment: I did that. do you know why it happened?

Comment: it is a gramma issue, compiler will think you would have one more validator after `MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class`, but you did not give the name

Comment: See my comment to the answer of Deco: a trailing comma is allowed by the JLS

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are declaring some sort of array of constraints. You are placing an extra comma (`,`) after your last constraint, thus making the compiler expect some other value together with the ones you already have. Try doing this:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {
        MinTimeIntCoConstraintValidator.class, 
        MinTimeIntCoListConstraintValidator.class,
        MinTimeDoubleCoConstraintValidator.class, 
        MinTimeDoubleCoListConstraintValidator.class
        })
```

Comment: See my comment to the answer of Deco: a trailing comma is allowed by the JLS.